# Getting error in curl command(curl: (35) error reading X.509 potentially-encrypted key file: Error in parsing.)

Tags: certificate, ubuntu-16.04, curl, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail

I am using  below command

```
curl   --insecure  --cert 'cert.p12:password'  -X GET   https://serverUrl   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'


curl   --insecure --cert-type P12 --cert 'cert.p12:password'  -X GET   https://serverUrl   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

it's not working in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l (AWS lightsail)
and giving below error

curl: (35) error reading X.509 potentially-encrypted key file: Error in parsing.

but working in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS \n \l (LOCAL SYSTEM)

Answer (score 0):

As In Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS  P12 file does not support so we can use below command

PKCS#1 Private key

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

Certificates:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pem
```

We can use the below command to call API

```
curl -k --cert ./publicCert.pem --cert-type PEM --key ./privateKey.pem --key-type PEM --pass password  -X GET   https://serverUrl   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```